# Trying to figure out why Excel freezes the second time I run the code

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if the code is janky, I'm pretty new.  I'm trying to write a macro that copy's a sheet, removes some unnecessary parts, and exports the sheet into vba.
It works fine the first time, but if I try to run the code twice while in the same instance of excel the whole thing freezes.  It doesn't matter if the csv file exists, and I've noticed that the error happens when the file saves as csv.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_CSV()
Dim WbPath As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    WbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fso.GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name) & " GRID UPLOAD.csv"
    If FileExist(WbPath) Then
        SetAttr WbPath, vbNormal
        Kill WbPath
    End If

    Sheets("GRID UPLOAD").Copy after:=Worksheets("GRID UPLOAD")
    ActiveSheet.Name = "GRID EXPORT"
    With Sheets("GRID Export")
        .Rows("1:3").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        .Cells.ClearFormats
        .Shapes("GRIDBUTTON").Delete
        .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
        .Move
    End With
   ' Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=WbPath, _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
   ' Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub


Function FileExist(FilePath As String) As Boolean


Dim TestStr As String

  On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Determine if File exists
  If TestStr = "" Then
    FileExist = False
  Else
    FileExist = True
  End If
```

Comment: I assume you mean twice in a row, not twice simultaneously in different workbooks (may not be even possible, but terrible idea if it is lol). For debugging purposes, can you step through the code and tell me the line where it fails/hangs on your second run?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this.  It fails on the ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Line the second run through.  It doesn't matter if it's overwriting a previously saved file or not, just that it's the second time ran in a row.

Comment: @SeanScott Not sure if it notifies you unless I tag you.  New to this site.

Comment: Welcome to SO by the way! It notifies everyone in the comments section whenever a new comment is posted. In the future, try to post as much info about the question as possible, such as error type and position and anything else that might be relevant.

Could you post the specific error either via text or screenshot? Also, does it only happen when you save as CSV or does it happen for XLS as well?

Comment: Well it doesn't provide an error.  Excel freezes and it tells me Excel is not responding.  And unfortunately it still freezes when saving as xlWorkbookNormal

Comment: Which Excel version are you using?

Comment: Also, can you try Changing your SaveAs to a Save and see if that works multiple times with an existing file? I would also like to see what the Windows Event log says when your program dies.

Comment: Excel 2013.  I'll try it out and get back with you.

Comment: So Save works fine.  I kind of need it to save the file as csv though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, think I have an answer for you. You have two options. The first is programmatic and guaranteed to get your code to work, though it will not "fix" the issue for future attempts. Do:

```
If FileExist(WbPath) Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=WbPath, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
```

This way, it will guarantee that you will never call SaveAs more than once for a given workbook.

On the other hand, you could try fixing your Excel 2013 version. SaveAs crashes are well-documented in the Office 2013 suite for some reason, and there are a few resources you can go to for help:

- https://superuser.com/questions/785696/save-as-causes-office-to-crash
- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/excel-2013-crashes-frequently-and-destroys/c3080b63-527a-4fdf-8c77-775348b84cf0?auth=1
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2758592

I hope my answer satisfies your problem. Please let me know if you require additional assistance.

Comment: Thanks!  This is actually the same thing I just wrote lol, thanks to you're problem solving earlier.  I really appreciate it, and I'm definitely going to look into office crashing.

Comment: Glad to help! When you accept answers on Stack Overflow, please also upvote. It helps your posters improve their rep.